# How to expand partition with block in the middle on windows?

Tags: windows, partition, windows-server-2019

I have a server with partition as below.
I have added free space to it but not able to extend the C: drive as expand option is greyed out.

[image: partition]

When I get that in personal laptop, I used to do with acronis disk diretory suite(cracked version), but this machine is now office server and can't ask them to buy the license for just this server.

Any window commands to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I normally use [GParted](https://gparted.org/)  for this kind of thing.

You should be able to move your recovery drive to the end which will allow you to expand into the now-adjacent space.

Also, take a look at DiskPart.  A Windows-native tool, good if you're struggling for GParted to 'see' your RAID controller etc, but GParted is great for the visual aspect.

Obviously, be **very** careful applying changes, ensure recent backups are available etc.

Comment: GParted looks like an ISO image, not an exe to install on that machine. I don't have vmware console access to attach it. I will check with the concerned team